# Finding the calling class of UIBUTTON?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a UIViewController, which is used in 2 different classes within same xib. I have created a uibutton in it and associated the action method in both the classes which are trying to use it.Both classes A and B have different outlets to that UIVIewController.

when i try to press the UIButton in the viewcontroller, both functions in Class (A) and Class (B) get called (since the event is on touch down) but the method names in each class is different.

Can I somehow check which class called the uiviewcontroller's button touch event?

Comment: post the button action please

Comment: interface A {
- (IBAction)cellNumbersSet:(id)sender
} 
interface B {
- (IBAction)cellNumberSet:(id)sender
}

Both interfaces have differnt outlets to same UIVIEWCOntroller, which contains the UIBUtton. THis Button has 2 action methods on touch up inside associated with it in both interfaces A and B respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag(different values) for Button from each class and in your button function first check the tag and execute respective action.

Comment: As I mentioned, There is only 1 UIVIEWController and I have designed it in IB and set the tag of button there to 1. But when i will press the button, both action methods will receive the sender with tag 1 :) ...any other thoughts ?

Comment: One main XIB, Class A represents the XIB. Within that XIB i had created another UIVIEWController(B) which is associated with the class B. Now there is this final UIVIEWController in the same XIB, which has a button and both class A and class B want to access that viewController( lets say "C").

Comment: the object of uiviewcontroller ,i want to say the instance,is the same in the two classes?

Comment: In which controller you created outlet for this button(FilesOwner)? Whats your actual requirement?

Comment: I created outlets in both of the classes A and B. So both classes have different instances of the same uiviewcontroller. but since the button in the uiviewcontroller has 2 action methods in class A and B respectively, both action methods are attached to "touch up inside" event. So both methods get called, even if i access UIViewController from class B.

Comment: I want to be able to distinguish which class is actually popping over the uiviewcontroller, and then clicking the button. Objective is to stop both methods(in class A and B) from executing at once...

Answer (score 0):

you can check with isKindOfClass if you have 2 classes

Comment: ...But when i will compare isKindOfClass ,it is my understanding that isKinfOfClass will happen like this : [sender isKindOfClass:@"A"], and sender being UIBUTTON type class, will return false ..Correct me, If i am wrong